# Serving API from another site behind the first one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, alias, virtualhost

I have old solution based on Drupal 7 and the new one based on Drupal 8. Both of them provide APIs for their mobile apps. (URLs can be easy distinguished) In order to maintain smooth migration for users I want to keep old solution working as it is and serve new version of API behind it, it has obvious difference in pattern like /oauth/token, /api/v1/*, /api/v2/*.

I have tried the different ways of configuring apache with I different results, but not exactly what I need. I tried:
Configuring virtual hosts together with Alias; 
Changing DocumentRoot to /var/www (where I have docroot with and docroot-new)
Configuring the .htaccess different ways

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ${APACHE_SERVERNAME}
    ServerAlias test.*
    DocumentRoot /var/www/docroot/
  #this is example with phpinfo, works well
    Alias "/info.php" "/var/www/docroot-new/"
    #Just to simplify I'm trying to serve only one API endpoint from    
    new solution
    Alias /api/v1/mobile-ui/ "/var/www/docroot-new/"
    #And auth endpoint
    Alias "/oauth/token/" "/var/www/docroot-new/"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/docroot/">
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/docroot-new/">
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In this case the old solution is served well, but the new one can't be handled appropriately.
If I change DocumentRoot to /var/www/ , then both of them will work well, but obviously with a dir name in url. I guess .htaccess can help me here, but I'm not an expert and can't find the solution.
I also switch-on addition logging for apache and able to check details like matching for mod_rewrite (actually not very helpful for me)

Answer (score 0):

so, I find the solution by myself. It's even better than previous thoughts. Just proxying queries.

```
ProxyPassMatch "/api(.*)"  "http://new-solution.local/api$1"
ProxyPassReverse "/api(.*)"  "http://new-solution.local/api$1"

ProxyPass "/oauth/token"  "http://new-solution.local/oauth/token"
ProxyPassReverse "/oauth/token"  "http://new-solution.local/oauth/token"
```

Hope it will help someone to solve similar problem.